# How to modify properties of the incoming object without creating a new instance?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to modify properties of the incoming object. How to do this without creating a new instance?

I have a class

```
public class Report : IReport<ReportItem>
{
    public Report()
    {
        Items = new ReportItemsCollection();
    }

    public Report(IEnumerable<ReportItem> items)
    {
        Items = new ReportItemsCollection(items);
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "items")]
    public ReportItemsCollection Items { get; private set; }

    IEnumerable<ReportItem> IReport<ReportItem>.Items
    {
        get { return Items; }
    }
}
```

and two methods

```
private static Report ConvertReportItems(Report report)
{
    var reportData = report.Items.Select(BackwardCompatibilityConverter.FromOld);
    return new Report(reportData);
}

public static ReportItem FromOld(ReportItem reportItem)
{
    reportItem.AgentIds = new List<Guid> { reportItem.AgentId };
    reportItem.AgentNames = new List<string> { reportItem.Agent };

    return reportItem;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain more on this.

Comment: I'm a little unclear but something like `reportData.Items = report.Items.Select(BackwardCompatibilityConverter.FromOld);` would change the existing item without creating a new one. Not sure if that is actually valid of course not knowing your object structure but you get the gist.

Comment: Why creating a new instance if you want to modify a property?  What is `Report`? You need to explain your problem more.

Comment: When I call `BackwardCompatibilityConverter.FromOld` I modify two properties. Why don't just modify properties of incoming object? What issues to try to prevent by creating a new instance?

Comment: Just a remark: it's generally bad practice to change the state of input parameters. Callers don't expect this and this might result in some hard-to-track bugs later on + it breaks encapsulation of the input parameter.

Comment: It seems like the code of `BackwardCompatibilityConverter.FromOld()` is more relevant to your question that what you've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to update the properties of each object in a collection with Linq.  Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  If you want to *update* the items in a collection, you'll have to loop:

```
foreach(ReportItem item in report.Items)
{
   // update item
}
```

Whether you *should* do this or not is another question, but mechanically that's how you *would* do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Report` allows you to set its properties. I'm going to suppose you've got a `Data` property or something like that, which has a setter.

```
private static void ConvertReportItems(Report report)
{
    report.Data = report.Items.Select(BackwardCompatibilityConverter.FromOld)
        .ToList();
}
```